# Rate of nutrient decay in fruit/vegetable juice

Tags: data-request, medical, food

I am looking for a dataset containing rate of nutrient decay in fruit/vegetable juice. It will probably depends how the juice is stored. The juice was made using a [personal juicer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002TUU392).

The goal is to make an educated decision about whether to use the juicer as needed (maximizing nutrient content but increasing cleanup effort) or to produce fruit/vegetable juice 6/12/18 hrs ahead of time (reducing cleanup effort but perhaps reducing nutrient content).

(The question was asked in a slightly different form on [Seasoned Advice Stack Exchange](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16433/10703) by [sibbaldiopsis](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/5668/sibbaldiopsis) but was closed there.)